# Organizing database tables - large number of properties

Tags: database, properties, database-relations

I have a database that stores some users in it. Each user has its account settings, privacy settings and lots of other properties to set. The number of those properties started to grow and I could end up with 30 properties or so.

Till now, I used to keep it in "UserInfo" table having User and UserInfo related as One-To-Many (keeping a log of all changes). Putting it in a single "UserInfo" table doesn't sound nice and, at least in the database model, it would look messy. What's the solution?

Separating privacy settings, account settings and other "groups" of settings in separate tables and have 1-1 relations between UserInfo and each group of settings table is one solution, but would that be too slow (or much slower) when retrieving the data? I guess all data would not be presented on a single page at the same moment. So maybe having one-to-many relationships to each table is a solution too (keeping log of each group separately)?

Answer (score 1):

If it's only 30 properties, I'd recommend just creating 30 columns.  That's not too much for a modern database to handle.

But I would guess that if you ahve 30 properties today, you will continue to invent new properties as time goes on, and the number of columns will keep growing.  Restructuring your table to add columns every day may become time-consuming as you get lots of rows.

For an alternative solution check out this blog for a nifty solution for storing lots of dynamic attributes in a "schemaless" way:  [How FriendFeed Uses MySQL](http://bret.appspot.com/entry/how-friendfeed-uses-mysql).

Basically, collect all the properties into some format and store it in a single TEXT column.  The format is semi-structured, that is your application can separate the properties if needed but you can also add more at any time, or even have different properties per row.  XML or YAML or JSON are example formats, or some object serialization format supported by your application code language.

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
  user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  user_proerties TEXT
);
```

This makes it hard to search for a given value in a given property.  So in addition to the TEXT column, create an auxiliary table for each property you want to be searchable, with two columns: values of the given property, and a foreign key back to the main table where that particular value is found.  Now you have can index the column so lookups are quick.

```
CREATE TABLE UserBirthdate (
  user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
  birthdate DATE NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id),
  KEY (birthdate)
);

SELECT u.* FROM Users AS u INNER JOIN UserBirthdate b USING (user_id)
WHERE b.birthdate = '2001-01-01';
```

This means as you insert or update a row in Users, you also need to insert or update into each of your auxiliary tables, to keep it in sync with your data.  This could grow into a complex chore as you add more auxiliary tables.